# Substring with reverse index

Tags: javascript, string

How can I extract "456" from "xxx_456" where xxx is of indefinite length?

Comment: This question would be so much more useful if it were phrased in a general way: "How can I extract the end of a string after the last occurrence of a given delimiter?".

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
var str = "xxx_456";
var str_sub = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("_")+1);
```

If it is not always three digits at the end (and seperated by an underscore). If the end delimiter is not always an underscore, then you could use regex:

```
var pat = /([0-9]{1,})$/;
var m = str.match(pat);
```

Comment: +1 lastIndexOf is exactly what you want here, faster than regex and more flexible than substr.

Comment: @Phil: not measurably faster, unless it's being called thousands of times. You'd need to call them millions of times before the difference would be noticeable.

Answer (score 200):

`slice` works just fine in IE and other browsers, it's part of the specification and it's the most efficient method too:

```
alert("xxx_456".slice(-3));
//-> 456
```

[slice Method (String) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w1bzf9f(VS.85).aspx)
[slice - Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Slice)

Comment: Note that the reverse would **not** work: ``"xxx_456".slice(3)``

Comment: @user1429980 If with "reverse" you mean to remove the last three digits it is `"xxx_456".slice(0, -3)`

Answer (score 28):

The [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method allows you to specify start and end index:

```
var str = "xxx_456";
var subStr = str.substring(str.length - 3, str.length);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can just split it up and get the last element

```
var string="xxx_456";
var a=string.split("_");
alert(a[1]); #or a.pop
```

Comment: +1, I would have provided the split-pop method in my own answer if you hadn't mentioned it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Simple regex for any number of digits at the end of a string:

```
'xxx_456'.match(/\d+$/)[0]; //456
'xxx_4567890'.match(/\d+$/)[0]; //4567890
```

or use split/pop indeed:

```
('yyy_xxx_45678901').split(/_/).pop(); //45678901
```

Comment: that was a clever :)
a performance friendly method

Answer (score 4):

```
alert("xxxxxxxxxxx_456".substr(-3))
```

caveat: according to [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/substr), not IE compatible

Comment: but `slice` is - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
String.prototype.reverse( ) {
     return Array.prototype.slice.call(this)
          .reverse()
          .join()
          .replace(/,/g,'')
}
```

using a reverse string method

```
var str = "xxx_456"
str = str.reverse() // 654_xxx 
str = str.substring(0,3) // 654 
str = str.reverse() //456
```

if your reverse method returns the string then chain the methods for a cleaner solution.

Comment: in what api does the reverse() method appear?

Comment: @MikeS. please +1 if this helped

Answer (score 2):

A crazy regex approach

```
"xxx_456".match(/...$/)[0] //456
```

Comment: could also be 'xxx_456'.match(/_.+$/)[0] or 'xxx_456'.replace(/(^.+_)(.+$)/,'$1')?

Comment: @Kooilnc: No need to overcomplicate regexes just because you can.  Your first example would also match the `_`.

Comment: @Andy E: you're right about the _. Second possibility: $1 should be $2 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

here is my custom function

```
function reverse_substring(str,from,to){
  var temp="";
  var i=0;
  var pos = 0;
  var append;      
  for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    //alert("inside loop " + str[i]);
    if(pos == from){
         append=true;
    }

    if(pos == to){
         append=false;
         break;
    }
    if(append){
         temp = str[i] + temp;
    }
    pos++;
  }
  alert("bottom loop " + temp);
}

var str = "bala_123";
reverse_substring(str,0,3);
```

This function works for reverse index.

Comment: is this complex? i just implemented substring in reverse fashion. thats it. and this is for what the user asked from his title.

Comment: too complex , just use `"xxxxxxx_456".slice(-3)`

Answer (score 2):

Also you can get the result by using `substring` and `lastIndexOf` -

```
alert("xxx_456".substring("xxx_456".lastIndexOf("_")+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, to support answer by [user187291](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400327/6082863)

In case of fixed length of desired substring I would use `substr()` with negative argument for its short and readable syntax

```
"xxx_456".substr(-3)
```

For now it is [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr#Browser_compatibility) with common browsers and not yet strictly deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

One way of extracting only the numbers

```
name = "xxx_456"
substring = reverse(reverse(name)[1:3])
substring
```